# How to type following expression in Mathematica

Tags: formatting, products

I want to eneter following expression in mathematica
$$\prod_a^3 \prod_{b\neq a}^3 \frac{x(a)}{b-a}$$

How is this extra condition in product entered in Mathematica?

Without the restriction, I would just use

```
Product[x[a]/(b - a), {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]
```

Now with this restriction, I wrote something like

```
If[b != a, Product[x[a]/(b - a), {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]]
```

But this does not seem to evaluate anything.

How do I put the condition $a\neq b$ in the product?

Comment: `Product[If[b == a, 1, x[a]/(b - a)], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]`

Answer (score 6):

```
Product[x[a]/(b - a), {a, Range[3]}, {b, Complement[Range[3], {a}]}]
```

> `-(1/4) x[1]^2 x[2]^2 x[3]^2`

Answer (score 2):

Equivalent way, without excluding pairs in the iterator:

```
Product[Which[a != b, x[a]/(b - a), a == b, 1], {a, 3}, {b, 3}]
```